# Mathematic's difficulties to understand the parametrisation of an electrostatic potential field

Tags: calculus, functions, parametric

I start to learn electrostatic and I have some problem with finding the upper and lower boundaries of my parametric variable that I used to represent the graph of the potential surfaces of two positive charges place in the z axis, (0,0,a) and (0,0,-a). Just to say, i'm not a student, i study physics for my own pleasure, and my level in math is a little rusted. Sorry if the question is dumb!

I'm not a very good english speaker, so here the math:

So I have

$$
r_-=\sqrt{x^2+y²+(z-a)²}
$$
$$
r_+=\sqrt{x^2+y²+(z+a)²}
$$

My equation is 
$$
\phi(X)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{r_-}+\frac{1}{r_+})
$$

I put $\rho=\sqrt{(\frac{x}{a})²+(\frac{y}{a})²}$, $\alpha=\frac{z}{a}$ and $V=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0a}{2Q}\phi(X)$. With that i have :

$$
V=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho²+\alpha²+1-2\alpha}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho²+\alpha²+1+2\alpha}})
$$

To parametrise this equation I put $\left|u \right|<1$ and also :

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho²+\alpha²+1-2\alpha}}= (1+u)V=\frac{a}{r_-}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho²+\alpha²+1+2\alpha}}= (1-u)V=\frac{a}{r_+}
$$

Little explanation of why i'm doing that. From the expressions i just wrote, i have:

$$
V=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{r_-} + \frac{a}{r_+}) \Leftrightarrow V=\frac{1}{2}((1+u)V + (1-u)V)
$$

Like $\left|u \right|<1$, the equality is respected:
$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow 1} V = \frac{1}{2}(2V+0)= V
$$
$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow -1} V = \frac{1}{2}(0+2V)= V
$$

From that, i'm able to get :

$$
\alpha=\frac{1}{V²(1-u²)²}
$$
$$
\rho=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{V²(1-u²)²}-1)(1-\frac{u²}{V²(1-u²)²})}
$$

And i have lot of difficulties here to find the upper and lower boundaries of $u$. I'm stuck here :

$$
\frac{1}{V(1-u²)}\geq 1 \geq \frac{\left|u \right|}{V(1-u²)}
$$

But form that point I don't know how to find $u_{sup}$ and $u_{inf}$.

If anybody can help me, thanks!

Comment: I think you go wrong before then. You introduce $u$ by two equations. How do you know that a single value of $u$ can satisfy both equations at the same time?